# Flask render_template does not update the page

Tags: python, flask, redirect, request, response

I am trying to upload a file, make some calculations to generate an image and then to display it. I came up with the following, but the page does not refresh after the `redirect`. Even though I get the correct codes:

```
"POST /result HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /display_image/census_2009b.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

[image: Not refreshed page]

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']
    ### generating and saving an image to `filename`...

    return redirect(url_for('display_image', filename=filename))

@app.route('/display_image/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def display_image(filename):
    image_url = url_for('static', filename=filename)
    return render_template('display_image.html', image_url=image_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

with `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/result" method="get" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `display_image.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uploaded Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="Uploaded image">
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Flask functions are fine, the issue is with Dropzone. Dropzone controls the upload process, so you have to use Dropzone to redirect once the upload is complete. [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413323/flask-redirect-doesnt-work-after-upload) for details on how to redirect with Dropzone.

I'd also consider implementing [Flask Dropzone](https://github.com/helloflask/flask-dropzone) (made by the guy who answered the question linked above), it has very good documentation.